# Add identifier to aws codebuild run name

Tags: amazon-web-services, build, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I have an aws codebuild resource that I run each time with different parameters. Is there a way to add text to the run name so I can distingiush between the different build runs ? Now it looks like this : My project:guid
exampe: run-codebuild:76321b7b-5ef9-46d7-adf4-f688654025d4

And what I want is to have : run-codebuild:My own unique identifier:76321b7b-5ef9-46d7-adf4-f688654025d4

Comment: You can't customize the buildARN to include your own identifier. What is the purpose of your identifier? Is it like a human readable build number? Or a way to group build runs like an alias?

Comment: I'm using it to run automation, I'd like each build run to be a test case, and have an identifier to know which test case it is from the build run list @SubinMathew